# Assigning the same attribute to multiple divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm designing an Instagram clone. I had a problem with the story feature. When the story opened, I made the lines above. These lines are made up of divs. They all have a common class. I made this for CSS design. But I made an active id that won't happen to all of them.

Those with active id will be white and their opacity will be 1. Those who do not have this id will have an opacity of 0.5

It works when you assign a single id. But when I assign the second id, only the first one works.

```js
const active = document.getElementById("active");

active.style.backgroundColor = "white";
active.style.opacity = 1;
```

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-container-item {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  opacity: 0.5;
  padding: 1px;
  flex: 1pt;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-container-item" id="active">A</div>
  <div class="flex-container-item">B</div>
  <div class="flex-container-item">C</div>
  <div class="flex-container-item">D</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ids are unique, use a class instead. Also, set your css in css, and toggle (or add/remove) your class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can multiple different HTML elements have the same ID if they're different elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-eleme)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant have multiple same ids because id should be unique, instead make active css class e.g.

```
.active {
   background-color: white;
   opacity: 1;
 }
```

and then conditionally apply this class to your divs that you want to activate

Comment: Thanks. It has been very functional for me. How could I not think of such a simple solution

Answer (score 2):

You can not assign same ID value to multiple HTML elements. Use "active" class on the class attribute and then get it in javascript like that.

const activeElements = document.getElementsByClassName("active");

Comment: Be aware that `.active` is offently used so be sure to be specific enough when you select it. You might need something like `document.querySelectorAll("div.flex-container div.flex-container-item.active")`